# question about different between two sentence

Tags: present-perfect

Yesterday  I couldn't find my wallet anywhere but this morning I found it.

Yesterday I could not have found my wallet anywhere but this morning I found it.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two sentences use two different modal verbs: **could** in the first sentence and **could have** in the second. The difference is that **could** describes an *actual* situation in the past and **could have** describes  *hypothetical* situation in the past.

> I **could** not find my wallet.

This describes an *actual* situation: I actually tried to find my wallet, but I failed.

> I **could** not **have** found my wallet.

This describes a *hypothetical* or *unreal* situation: I never tried to find my wallet, but I believe that if had tried, I would have failed.